# Pradikshinam of navagraha

Tags: practice, navagraha

I was told by a person that the last 2 pradakshinams to be done anti clockwise for rahu and kethu. But one other kurukkal said that you do all the nine in clockwise only. 
Which to be followed? kindly give the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Rahu and Kethu are chaya grahas. They will travel alongwith other graha as per kocharas. An experienced sivan temple archaka in  Chennai  said do all the nine pradakshinams in clockwise direction only.

Comment: You may ask for significance or source for 9 pradakshina in clockwise direction to temple archaka.

Comment: I mentioned you know Rahu and Kethu are chaya grahas. They will travel alongwith other graha as per kocharas. This is the siginificance as per that archak.a